# How to add item into selectize js automatically after document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have selectize js code. It runs well and shows right option after i type key on select box.

Here is the code :

```
$('#select-links').selectize({
        maxItems: diffItems,
        valueField: 'nick_name',
        labelField: 'full_name',
        searchField: ['nick_name', 'full_name'],
        options: [],
        create: false,
        render: {
            item: function(item, escape) {
                return '<div id="' + escape(item.id) + '">' +
                    '<span class="nick_name">' + escape(item.full_name) + '</span>' +
                    '<span class="full_name"> &lt;' + escape(item.nick_name) + '&gt;</span>' +
                '</div>';
            },
            option: function(item, escape) {
                return '<div class="box-user clearfix">' +
                      '<div class="thumb col-xs-1 mr10">' +
                          '<img class="lazyload" src="'+escape(item.avatar)+'" data-src="' + escape(item.avatar)+'">' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<div class="col-xs-8">' +
                          '<span class="label" style="color: #000;">' + escape(item.full_name) + '</span>' +
                          '<span class="caption">/' + escape(item.nick_name) + '</span>' +
                      '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            }
        },
        load: function(query, callback) {
            if (!query.length) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/origin/search',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    q: query
                },
                error: function() {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    callback(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

But, i got the problem.

After document ready, i want selectize add item automatically after document / page has already loaded without i have to type the key on select box. How is the code?

```
    @if(isset($_POST['nick']))
        $(".chat__list--active").show();
        $(".edit").hide();
        $('.chat__list').hide();
        $('#cancel-participants').show();
        if(diffItems != 49) {
            $('#save-participants').show();
        }
        alert("{{$_POST['nick']}}");

        // This is the code's place to add item automatically and the key is $_POST['nick']
    @endif
```

Thank you.
Sorry for bad english

Comment: Yeeeh sorry, not sure what you are after?

Comment: Just add the items you want to be selected by default to the `value` attribute of the `input` field.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `options` to existing `selectize` by following approach:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectize_element = $("#select-links")[0].selectize;
     selectize_element.addOption({
        text:'First Item',
        value: 'First Item'
    });
    selectize_element.refreshOptions() ;
    selectize_element.addItem('First Item');
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think ajax '/ajax/origin/search' run first to get return value and set the item into selectize box.

Comment: So in that case try calling above piece of code (code within doc ready) after ajax success callback. Ajax will put data coming from server and then we will append the other option as per our need.

Comment: By using the same string for the "text" and "value" field, people don't know whether they should use the "text" or the "value" field content for the addItem() call.